# Can you define DOM Helper?

Tags: javascript

I ran across the word DOM helper.  I know what DOM stands for, but how would one really define the term DOM Helper?

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: @Jordan I was just looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684917/what-questions-should-a-javascript-programmer-be-able-to-answer/1684945#1684945  (I'm learning Javascript) and I just wondered what he meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DOM Helper is basically a wrapper for the DOM and DOM Elements (html/xml, but usually html) that solves cross browser discrepancies and adds higher level methods making dealing with the DOM a nicer experience.

jQuery and DOMAssistant are both good examples of DOM Helpers.

Answer (score 1):

A library that makes DOM manipulation easier by providing utility functions that do appending, inserting and such...?